# Square Up payment gateway form with ajax

Tags: javascript, wordpress, payment-gateway, square-connect

I am creating a new payment option in website. I implemented the square space successfully. But it creates issue when some one removes any item from the cart.

When ajax is called, it loads the whole content again. but then, form doesn't load and shows `console error undefined object SqPaymentForm.`

```
var sqPaymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({

  // Replace this value with your application's ID (available from the merchant dashboard).
  // If you're just testing things out, replace this with your _Sandbox_ application ID,
  // which is also available there.
  applicationId: '***********',
  inputClass: 'sq-input',
  cardNumber: {
    elementId: 'sq-card-number',
    placeholder: "0000 0000 0000 0000"
  },
  cvv: {
    elementId: 'sq-cvv',
    placeholder: 'CVV'
  },
  expirationDate: {
    elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
    placeholder: 'MM/YY'
  },
  postalCode: {
    elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
    placeholder: 'Postal Code'
  },
  inputStyles: [

    // Because this object provides no value for mediaMaxWidth or mediaMinWidth,
    // these styles apply for screens of all sizes, unless overridden by another
    // input style below.
    {
      fontSize: '14px',
      padding: '3px'
    },

    // These styles are applied to inputs ONLY when the screen width is 400px
    // or smaller. Note that because it doesn't specify a value for padding,
    // the padding value in the previous object is preserved.
    {
      mediaMaxWidth: '400px',
      fontSize: '18px',
    }
  ],
  callbacks: {
    cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData) {
      if (errors) {
        var errorDiv = document.getElementById('errors');
        errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
          var p = document.createElement('p');
          p.innerHTML = error.message;
          errorDiv.appendChild(p);
        });
      } else {
        // This alert is for debugging purposes only.
        alert('Nonce received! ' + nonce + ' ' + JSON.stringify(cardData));

        // Assign the value of the nonce to a hidden form element
        var nonceField = document.getElementById('card-nonce');
        nonceField.value = nonce;

        // Submit the form
        document.getElementById('form').submit();
      }
    },
    unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
      // Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported
    }
  }
});
```

I am using default code provided by gateway doc. Payment option is addon of event manager pro.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have forgotten to include this line

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform"></script>`

Also note that Square and Squarespace are very different companies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am including this. If I try to load it with out ajax then it is working but with ajax it doesn't load up. try to call the form with ajax. Sorry that is my mistake about square up and square space.

Comment: If you are loading the external library with ajax, you need to delay execution of the code `var sqPaymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({...` until you are sure that the library has loaded. Right now it sounds like you have a situation where the external script has been delayed, but execution is continuing with some code that relies on it.

Comment: I try delay. But in console it show message of connection but form doesn't load. I try eval as well. But that also doesn't work. can you check it at your end and see if that work for you with ajax and suggest me a better way.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have to load the library asynchronously? It will block your page rendering, or alter the look of your page because of the way the code will edit the forms.

Comment: The topic of script loading and deferring execution is pretty lengthy, see [HTML5Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/) the [onLoad event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp). It would also be helpful if you shared your complete code, the example from the Square website doesn't help that much.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/shwetashah246/o7wfp9nv/3/)

`

```
/* onGetCardNonce is triggered when the "Pay $1.00" button is clicked */
function onGetCardNonce(event) {
    /* Don't submit the form until SqPaymentForm returns with a nonce */
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Request a nonce from the SqPaymentForm object */
    paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
}

function Initialize(){
    console.log("Initialize square");

    /* Create and initialize a payment form object */
    const paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
        /*  Initialize the payment form elements*/
        /* TODO: Replace with your sandbox application ID */
        applicationId: "{API_KEY}",
        inputClass: 'sq-input',
        autoBuild: false,
        /* Customize the CSS for SqPaymentForm iframe elements*/
        inputStyles: [{
            fontSize: '16px',
            lineHeight: '24px',
            padding: '16px',
            placeholderColor: '#a0a0a0',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        }],
        /*  Initialize the credit card placeholders */
        cardNumber: {
            elementId: 'sq-card-number',
            placeholder: '{card_number}',
        },
        cvv: {
            elementId: 'sq-cvv',
            placeholder: '{cvv}',
        },
        expirationDate: {
            elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
            placeholder: '{mmyy}',
        },
        postalCode: {
            elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
            placeholder: '{postal}',
        },
        /*SqPaymentForm callback functions*/
        callbacks: {
            /*
            * callback function: cardNonceResponseReceived
            * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm completes a card nonce request
            */
            cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData) {
                var errorDiv = $("#square-form-error");
                errorDiv.html("");
                if (errors) {
                    /* Log errors from nonce generation to the browser developer console. */
                    console.error('Encountered errors:');
                    errors.forEach(function (error) {
                        console.error('  ' + error.message);
                        errorDiv.append('<div class="alert alert-danger m-t-15"><strong>' + error.message + '</strong></div>');
                    });
                    /*alert('Encountered errors, check browser developer console for more details');*/
                    return;
                }
                /* add card_nonce and card_zip parameters */
                var $nonceInput = $('<input/>').attr({'name':'card_nonce','value':nonce,'type':'text'});
                var $billingPostalCode = $('<input/>').attr({'name':'card_zip','value':cardData.billing_postal_code,'type':'text'});
                $('#square-form-container').append($nonceInput);
                $('#square-form-container').append($billingPostalCode);
                /* submit form  */
                $('#square-form-container').closest('form')[0].submit();
                /*nonce  */
            },
            unsupportedBrowserDetected: function() {
                /* Alert the buyer that their browser is not supported*/
                alert("browser does not support ");
            }
        }
    });

    /* call after Initialization*/
    paymentForm.build();
}

(function() {
   setTimeout(function() { Initialize(); }, 5000);
})();
```

`

Comment: It looks like your fiddle link is broken. Can you re-link?

Comment: I keep getting `(index):109 Uncaught ReferenceError: paymentForm is not defined at onGetCardNonce ((index):109)`

Comment: [new_js_fiddle_link](https://jsfiddle.net/shwetashah246/x9c1pns6/)
Try this

Comment: Thanks, it's loading fine without any issue but now I keep getting `Error: Form not initialise.` when I try to get a nonce. I'm pretty certain I see the form initialized when it loads though? I added a button click that just calls function getNonce? Can you assist?